# How do I insert equal elements into a BTreeMap?

Tags: rust, set

I am working on a project where I need an Ordered Set and I use a BTreeSet for that.
The Elements in my BTreeSet are `PItem` they are basically just a tuple of an `Item` and an `OrderedFloat`, like this: `struct PItem((Item, OrderedFloat<f64>))` -> read like `struct PItem(Item, weight)`
Now the tricky part: My BTreeMap should order the PItems only based on the weight, disregarding the Item.
If my BTreeMap already contains an PItem on the other hand should only be determined by the Item, disregarding the weight. Here is my Implementation for Ord and Eq for Item and PItem:

```
use ordered_float::OrderedFloat;
use std::cmp::Ordering;

#[derive(Eq)]
pub struct Item{
    pub s_i: u32,
    pub e_i: u32,
    pub val: String,
}
#[derive(Eq)]
pub struct PItem(pub Item, pub OrderedFloat<f64>);

impl Item{
    pub fn start(&self) -> u32{
        self.s_i
    }
    pub fn end(&self) -> u32{
        self.e_i
    }

    pub fn val(&self) -> &str{
        &self.val
    }
}

impl PItem{
    pub fn start(&self) -> u32{
        self.item().start()
    }
    pub fn end(&self) -> u32{
        self.item().end()
    }
    pub fn prob(&self) -> &OrderedFloat<f64>{
        &(self.1)
    }
    pub fn val(&self) -> &str{
        self.item().val()
    }
    pub fn item(&self) -> &Item{
        return &self.0
    }
}

impl PartialOrd for Item {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        if self.s_i == other.s_i{
            if self.e_i == other.e_i{
                return self.val.partial_cmp(&(other.val));
            }
            return self.e_i.partial_cmp(&(other.e_i));        
        }
        return self.s_i.partial_cmp(&(other.s_i));
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Item {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.s_i.eq(&(other.s_i)) && self.e_i.eq(&(other.e_i)) && self.val.eq(&(other.val))
    }
}

impl Ord for PItem {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &PItem) -> Ordering {
        if self.prob() == other.prob(){
            return self.item().cmp(&(other.item()));       
        }
        return self.prob().cmp(&(other.prob()));
    }
}


impl PartialOrd for PItem {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<Ordering> {
        if self.prob() == other.prob(){
            return self.item().partial_cmp(&(other.item()));        
        }
        return self.prob().partial_cmp(&(other.prob()));
    }
}

impl PartialEq for PItem {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.item().eq(&(other.item()))
    }
}

impl Ord for Item {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Item) -> Ordering {
        if self.start() == other.start(){
            if self.end() == other.end(){
                return self.val().cmp(&(other.val()));
            }
            return self.end().cmp(&(other.end()));        
        }
        return self.start().cmp(&(other.start()));
    }
}
```

Now however, I see that I can add the "same" PItem twice to the BTreeMap, when they have different weights. When everything is equal including the weight, I cannot insert it.

What I want is that I already cannot insert it even if the weight is different but the `Item`'s are equal. So apparently it takes the weight into consideration when deciding if an Item is already present in the set. Why is that? I cannot find my mistake in the code. When I check only for equality without adding any PItem to some set, the eq method seems to work fine.

Comment: `BtreeMap` uses your `Ord` implementation to decide whether two items are equal. Since your `Ord` implmentation for `PItem` takes the floating-point number (which I guess is the "weight") into account, so weill `BTreeMap`.

Comment: As a side note, your impls are much more complicated than they'd need to be. For `Item`, you can simply use the derive macros to get the same result. For `PItem`, you can use the derive macros if you change the order of the two fields. If you want to explicitly write the impls, you can use tuple comparison, e.g. `(&self.1, &self.0).cmp(&(&other.1, &other.0))`.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to order based on the weight but de-duplicate based on the item, but this is not something a simple `BTreeSet` is equipped to handle. You might want to keep a `HashSet<Rc<Item>>` on the side in order to check for duplicates before inserting into the `BTreeSet`.

Comment: Thats Exactly what I want! Why is a BTreeSet not suited for that?

Comment: A `BTreeSet` will use your `Ord` implementation to do a sort of binary search to find the appropriate place to insert a new item. So if you have 100 elements in your set, with weights 0-99, and insert a `PItem` with weight 100 but the same item as the element with weight 0, then the `BTreeSet` will never even consider checking that element with weight 0 since it knows that the new item will not be place anywhere near it. In reality the implementation details of `BTreeSet` make it more complicated to reason about than a BST, but that's the rough idea.